# How to normalize Difference of Gaussian Image pixels with negative values?

Tags: image-processing, gaussian, sift

In the context of image processing for edge detection or in my case a basic SIFT implementation:

When taking the 'difference' of 2 Gaussian blurred images, you are bound to get pixels whose difference is negative (they are originally between 0 - 255, when subtracting they are possibly between -255 - 255). What is the normal approach to 'fixing' this? I don't see taking the absolute value to be very correct in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different approaches depending on what you want to do with the output.

The first is to offset the output by 128, so that your calculation range of -128 to 127 maps to 0 to 255.

The second is to clamp negative values so that they all equal zero.

Comment: For the first method, what about the remaining calculation range of -255 to -129 and 128 to 255 ? (Specifically the -255 to -129)

Comment: @RodrigoSalazar you can either divide by 2 before adding 128, or you can clamp the result again. Sadly there's no good way to make 9 bits fit into 8. In most applications where you do a difference like this the magnitude will rarely be high enough where this is a problem.

Comment: Within the context of image processing and computing the difference b/w two images ... What does the negative values mean either way ?